# Immutability vs state change in a class

Tags: java, oop, immutability

I'm fairly new to the concept of immutable classes.
Consider this class:

```
public class ConnectionMonitor implements MessageConsumer {

    private final MonitorObject monitorObject;
    private boolean isConnected = true;

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ConnectionMonitor.class);

    public ConnectionMonitor(final MonitorObject monitorObject) {
        this.monitorObject = monitorObject;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }

    public void waitForReconnect() {
        logger.info("Waiting for connection to be reestablished...");
        synchronized (monitorObject) {
            enterWaitLoop();
        }
    }

    private void enterWaitLoop() {
        while (!isConnected()) {
            try {
                monitorObject.wait();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("Exception occured while waiting for reconnect! Message: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void notifyOnConnect() {
        synchronized (monitorObject) {
            monitorObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final IMessage message) {
        if (message.getType() == IMessage.Type.CONNECTION_STATUS) {
            final String content = message.getContent();
            logger.info("CONNECTION_STATUS message received. Content: " + content);
            processConnectionMessageContent(content);
        }
    }

    private void processConnectionMessageContent(final String messageContent) {
        if (messageContent.contains("Disconnected")) {
            logger.warn("Disconnected message received!");
            isConnected = false;
        } else if (messageContent.contains("Connected")) {
            logger.info("Connected message received.");
            isConnected = true;
            notifyOnConnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how this class could be changed to an immutable one.

In particular, I don't see how the boolean field `isConnected` could be made final, since it represents the connection state.

All clients of `ConnectionMonitor` should just query 
`isConnected()` to get the connection state.

I'm aware that locking changes to `isConnected` is possible or using an atomic boolean.

But I don't see how to rewrite this to an immutable class.

Comment: Not all objects should be immutable.

Comment: So I need just more experience to judge on when to create mutable/immutable classes?!

Comment: Experience helps. In general, prefer immutability when possible -- but only when possible. I've added more detail in an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The ideal is to *minimize* mutability -- not eliminate it.**

Immutable objects have multiple advantages. They're simple, thread-safe and may be shared freely.

However, sometimes we need mutability.

In "Effective Java," Joshua Bloch suggests these guidelines:

> - Classes should be immutable unless there's a very good reason to make them mutable.
> - If a class cannot be made immutable, limit its mutability as much as possible.

In your example, there's a very good reason for instances of the class to be mutable. But you can also see the second guideline in play: the field `monitorObject` is marked final.

Comment: Sounds like reasonable advice. After querying on the subject I got the expression that all classes should be immutable. But I wonder how that can be done and why not using a pure functional programming language instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put that state somewhere else. But for your situation, is it logical to? You should ask yourself that.

**Maybe it's best to leave `ConnectionMonitor` mutable. It's responsible for "monitoring" a connection, so it's bound to keep track of values that may change.** Otherwise, you'll need another object that *is* mutable to keep track of that state.

If that's not convincing enough, then here are some ways:

You could have a container class for your monitors, which map ConnectionMonitors to it's ConnectionState:

```
class MonitorManager {
    Map<ConnectionMonitor, Boolean> connectionStatuses = ...;
}
```

To make it simple, you could pass this manager to each monitor, allowing the listener to access the map and change the boolean value for that connection:

```
class ConnectionMonitor {
    private MonitorManager manager;

    //....

    private void processConnectionMessageContent(final String messageContent) {
        if (messageContent.contains("Disconnected")) {
            logger.warn("Disconnected message received!");
            manager.connectionStatuses.put(this, false);
        } else if (messageContent.contains("Connected")) {
            logger.info("Connected message received.");
            manager.connectionStatuses.put(this, true);
            notifyOnConnect();
        }
    }
}
```

But some developers would line up to tell you child objects should not know about their containers.

So create a new object thats responsible for the data gathered while monitoring the connection:

```
class MonitorManager {
    private Map<ConnectionMonitor, MonitoredData> data = ...;

    public void createMonitor() {
        MonitoredData data = new MonitoredData();
        this.data.put(new ConnectionMonitor(data), data);
    }
}

class ConnectionMonitor inplements MessageConsumer {
    private MonitoredData data;

    public ConnectionMonitor(MonitoredData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    //...

   private void processConnectionMessageContent(final String messageContent) {
        if (messageContent.contains("Disconnected")) {
            logger.warn("Disconnected message received!");
        data.setConnected(false);
    } else if (messageContent.contains("Connected")) {
            logger.info("Connected message received.");
            data.setConnected(true);
            notifyOnConnect();
        }
    }
}

class MonitoredData {
    private boolean connected;

    public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
        this.connected = connected;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }
}
```

Maybe the details in `MonitoredData` would better fit in the object that is being monitored. Would be easier to help if you gave more context.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer and alternatives. But in my style I try to avoid setters/mutators like 'MonitoredData'. So far I believe that immutable classes are more useful for value objects, but ConnectionMonitor has identity.

Comment: @Juergen I understand, I too use a more behavioral style. But to abide by that, `connected` would have to be set when the `connect()` or `disconnect()` are called (state modified by behavior). But in this case, you are not in control of calling such methods (if you are, thats the route that you should take). Although objects have behavior, some objects are data objects (persistant storage for example, which `read` represents a getter in basic form, and `create` or `add` represents a setter in a sense)

Answer (score -1):

No real-life object(when not considering single purpose classes) outside of textbook or paradigm zealot cellar is 100% immutable or stateless. Those who preach immutability at expos every time they get a chance usually just like the sound of their voice a lot. There is always some degree of mutability, but the key here is doing it in safe and non-violent manner and not mutate objects just because. If you can reason why certain part of the object should be mutable and you know all possible side-effects before hand, it is perfectly fine for it to be mutable. As you said, the boolean `isConnected`needs to have setter and getter or some other mechanism for it to reflect the current connection status. And since it is basically a binary switch that has only two states, the impact of it being mutable is minimal. You could achieve the same result in some other way, but you would have to go  through hoops and loops to achieve it with outsider method from different class.

TL;DR: Mutable state is not evil itself, but it can be misused to cause great evil.

Comment: Just wondering, why the downvotes? I don't think my answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you are one of those people who say that if it's immutable, then we should not call it an "object", but if you really believe that nobody ever writes Java classes that only have `final` fields, then I can show you a few thousand counter examples.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but the claim that no real-life object is immutable is clearly not true (`String`, `BigInteger`, `Double`, `ImmutableList`, `new int[0]`, most enum constants, `Locale`, etc etc). The point here is that not all classes should be immutable, not that there's no point in immutability.

Comment: In addition, the ad hominem arguments have no value.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Ok then, maybe I should reword my answer. I don't claim there is no point in immutability, but then again considering immutability of single-purpose class like String is like considering air is 100% air, despite it being made of other substances as well. By object I mean the whole designed functionality of classes used to solve problems. String does not solve problems, its purpose is to store char sequences. Surely, single-purpose classes should be immutable,cant argue there. But then you would spend your whole life writing single purpose "puzzle" classes and not be productive.